# Why do I get different boolean results, when they should be the same?

Tags: javascript, boolean

Why do I get different results when the results should be the same?

```
    let isPasswordValid = password => {
  if (!password.length <= 7) {
    return true;
  }
};

console.log(isPasswordValid("rondellallard"));  //true
console.log(isPasswordValid("passwordwfwfw"));  //true
console.log(isPasswordValid("ronde"));          //true
console.log(isPasswordValid("rondelltgh"));     //true
console.log(isPasswordValid("ronde42425"));     //true
```

//Code page 2

```
  let isPasswordValid = password => {
  if (password.length >= 7) {
    return true;
  }
};

console.log(isPasswordValid("rondellallard")); //true
console.log(isPasswordValid("passwordwfwfw")); //true
console.log(isPasswordValid("ronde")); //undefined
console.log(isPasswordValid("rondelltgh")); //true
console.log(isPasswordValid("ronde42425")); //true
```

When I reverse the more than and less than signs I believe I should still get the same values. How ever when I do, that is not the result that I get. The 3rd value which is always supposed to be undefined in this example turns up to be tre in the first example, and I don't understand why.

Comment: what about below ?
`const isPasswordValid = password => !password.length <= 7;`

Comment: You are essentially converting the `password.length` value to a boolean by `negating` it.

You need to specify the order of operations using brackets like:
`!(password.length <= 7)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the order of operations matters here (which is defined by [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table)). With your first if-statement:

```
if(!password.length <= 7)
```

your `password.length` gets converted to a boolean due to the `!` operator. Then, as this boolean value is being used in the context of an inequality, it will be converted to a number, where `true` becomes `1` and `false` becomes `0`. So, your `if` condition will always evaluate to `true` as `0/1 <= 7`.

In your second if-statement however,

```
if (password.length >= 7) {
```

you are actually checking the length of the string. Your function will `return true` if your password length is 7 or greater. However, you haven't defined what it should do if this is not the case, so by default, your function will return `undefined` implicitly.